# Set time for Custom Dialog

Tags: android, timer, dialog

When the user clik on Register Button, a Custom Dialog box appear and the user move to the menu. But in my case, the Costum Dialog appear just for one second and then the user pass to the next layout.

How to set a time for the Custom Dialog please ?

Here my code :

```
    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    final String name = inputName.getText().toString();
                    final String mail = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                    final String password = inputPassword.getText()
                            .toString();

                    PatientFunctions patientFunction = new PatientFunctions();

                    json = patientFunction.registerPatient(name, mail,
                            password);

                    try {
                        if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                            String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                            if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                                Intent main = new Intent(
                                        getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                                main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(main);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            CustomizeDialog customizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(RegisterPatient.this);
            customizeDialog.show(); 

                            Handler handler = null;
            handler = new Handler(); 
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ 
                 public void run(){
                     customizeDialog.cancel();
                     customizeDialog.dismiss();
                 }
            }, 3000);

        }
    });
```

Comment: u want to show a dialog while waiting for "http" request, right?

Comment: I want to dismiss the diaolog and move to the next layout (intent) at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many good options including [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) & [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)

You can use a [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) too like so:

```
Handler handler = null;
handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ 
     public void run(){
         customdialog.cancel();
         customdialog.dismiss();
     }
}, 500);
```

Comment: Thank you !! But it not working when I edited my code. I move directly to the next layout (Intent)

Comment: @Farbhyn whats not working, whats happening instead?

Comment: In fact, the Dialog Box appear and disappear directly (0.5 second) and next I move to the next layout. I think that because the two threads works in the same time, I'm not sure :/

Comment: @Farbhyn is that not what you wanted, if not what should it do?

Comment: @Farbhyn if you want them on the same thread, the first `Runnable` you create, create a variable for it. `Runnable run = new Run...` then in the `handler` instead of creating a new one refer to it by the variable name

Comment: Vote up requires 15 reputations ^^'

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do these kind of process is to use **[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)** class

and override **onPreExecute** and **doInBackground** and **onPostExecute**

see [the official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

> implement the doInBackground() callback method, which runs in a pool of background threads. To update your UI, you should implement onPostExecute(), which delivers the result from doInBackground() and runs in the UI thread, so you can safely update your UI. You can then run the task by calling execute() from the UI thread

```
private class Registration extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    CustomizeDialog customizeDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // show ur dialog
        customizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(RegisterPatient.this);
        customizeDialog.show(); 
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        final String name = params[0];
        final String email = params[1];
        final String password = params[2];

        PatientFunctions patientFunction = new PatientFunctions();

        json = patientFunction.registerPatient(name, mail,
                password);

        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                return res;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
            if(customizeDialog != null)
                customizeDialog.dismiss();

            Intent main = new Intent(
                    getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
            main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            //move to the next activity
            startActivity(main);
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit**

and then execute it what ever you want

```
buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String name = inputName.getText().toString();
                final String mail = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText()
                        .toString();
                new Registration().execute(name,mail,password);
            }
     });
```